# Address each dimension of a 3-D array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, for-in-loop

I've been trying for the past few days learn how to insert data into every index in a 3-D array in swift. I am attempting to populate a 3-D array through a for-in loop. I know this example isn't correct because I'm not address each dimension in the array when I attempt to place in a value for the array, but I don't know how else to show what I mean:

```
var arr = [[[String]]]()
var brand = ["ford", "dodge", "toyota", "ford", "Nissan"]
var engine = ["2.0", "2.5", "3.4", "4.0", "5.0"]
var gas_mile = ["30", "25", "20", "15", "10"]

for index_1 in 1...brand.count{
    arr[index_1] = brand[index_1]

    for index_2 in 1...engine.count{
        arr[index_1][index_2] = engine[index_2] 

        for index_3 in 1...gas_mile.count{
             arr[index_1][index_2][index_3] = gas_mile[index_3]
        }
    }
}
```

I know you need to have an index for every dimension of the array ex:

```
 arr[0][0][0] = gas_mile[0]
```

But I don't know how you would then add something to the first dimension of the array because the swift compiler is expecting a 2-D array ([[String]]) to be added, not a single value:

```
arr[0] = brand[0]
```

So I am confused how I would address the first or second dimension of the array in adding a value to it. I have little experience with swift, that's why I am asking on how you can address each individual dimension.

Comment: Since your code does not compile it's now easy to understand what you want to do. It seems you are building a 5 x 5 x 5 array. Could you describe how the generic cell `(i, j, k)` should be populated?

Comment: I want it to be something like this: `brand:engine:gas mileage`  so it would look like something like this for the first dimension and all of the other cells `(ford, 2.0, 30), (ford, 2.5, 25), (ford, 3.4, 20), (ford, 4.0, 15), (ford, 5.0, 10)` I didn't to add 6 values for the gas_mile array, I meant the 5 x 5 x 5 array

Comment: Wrap your 3 components into an object/struct, named `MyIndex`. Make it `Hashable`, create dictionary `[MyIndex: String]`. Would that work for you?

Comment: I'm not for sure like I said I have little experience with swift, so I will take a look into that. Thank you for the input on it and giving a solution to my problem. I just thought it would be easier to address it the for-in-loop, but I was very wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution

```
struct Archive {
    private var dict = [String:[String:Int]]()

    func miles(byBrand brand: String, andEngine engine: String) -> Int? {
        return dict[brand]?[engine]
    }

    mutating func set(miles: Int, forBrand brand: String, andEngine engine:String) {
        var milesDict = dict[brand] ?? [String:Int]()
        milesDict[engine] = miles
        dict[brand] = milesDict
    }
}
```

### How does it work?

As you can see data is stored in a dictionary where the key is the `brand name` and the value is another dictionary which has as key the engine and as value the miles.

### How to use it

Step 1: create your `Archive` value

```
var archive = Archive()
```

Step 2: store data

```
archive.set(miles: 1, forBrand: "Ford", andEngine: "2.0")
archive.set(miles: 2, forBrand: "Ford", andEngine: "3.0")
archive.set(miles: 3, forBrand: "Ford", andEngine: "4.0")
archive.set(miles: 4, forBrand: "Ford", andEngine: "5.0")
archive.set(miles: 5, forBrand: "Audi", andEngine: "2.0")
```

Step 3: read data

```
archive.miles(byBrand: "Ford", andEngine: "2.0") // 1
archive.miles(byBrand: "Ford", andEngine: "3.0") // 2
archive.miles(byBrand: "Ford", andEngine: "4.0") // 3
archive.miles(byBrand: "Ford", andEngine: "5.0") // 4
archive.miles(byBrand: "Audi", andEngine: "3.0") // 5
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. I really appreciate the explanation of how it works and the description.